# Как передать значение в textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Делаю простенькую систему комментариев. Хочу чтобы при клике на имя значение заносилось в value поля textarea. Как примерно это должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вызвать `val(name)`?

```js
$(function(){
  $(".name").click(function() {
      $("#somecomment").val("@" + $(this).text());
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="somecomment"></textarea>
<br />
<a href="#" class="name">Aaa</a>
<br />
<a href="#" class="name">Bbb</a>
<br />
<a href="#" class="name">Ccc</a>
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно